# jquery problem- function repeats

Tags: jquery

I have two thumbnails in `<a>` tag by clicking them another image (main image) `src` will change to `<a> hrefs` tag to show fullsize image.

The function works, but problem is that when I track the function It will repeat relatively to number of clicks.

If its 1st click it runs once, if its 2nd click it runs twice and so on. Here is my code:

```
<div class="wraptocenter"><img alt="" src=""  id="myim"  /></div>
  <a href="images/cam1.jpg" class="changemimg"> <img alt="" src="images/10.jpg"  /></a> 
   <a href="images/cam.jpg" class="changemimg" ><img alt="" src="images/9.jpg" /></a> 
   <img src="" id="hiddenimg" style="display:none" />



$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".changemimg").bind('click', set);
    function set() {
        $("#myim").attr("src", "images/indicators.gif");
        var path = $(this).attr("href")
        $("#hiddenimg").attr("src", path);
        $("#hiddenimg").load(function () { alert('hi'); $("#myim").attr("src", path); });
        return false;

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly obvious. Do you mind creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is a convenient tool for this.

Comment: Upload the code on JSFIDDLE.net

Comment: can you please show us the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".changemimg").bind('click', set);

    function set(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

        $("#myim").attr("src", "images/indicators.gif");
        var path = $(this).attr("href");
        var myimg = new Image();
        $(myimg)
            .load(function(){
                alert('hi');
                $('#myim').attr('src', path);
            })
            .attr('src', path);
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/V74Sh/)

Answer (score 1):

Your Load event handler on the "hiddenimg" element is set everytime the anchor element is clicked. So after each click the number of Load event handlers are increasing by one.
Following code should resolve your issue

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var path;
        $(".changemimg").bind('click', set);
        $("#hiddenimg").load(function () {
            alert('hi');
            $("#myim").attr("src", path);
        });
        function set() {
            $("#myim").attr("src", "images/Calendaricon.gif");
            path = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#hiddenimg").attr("src", path);
            $("#hiddenimg").attr("style", "display:block");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: both anwers are true but i can choose one as answer,